# JQuery Get all <alt> tags from an <img> and show them in an <ul><li>

Tags: jquery, html, image, galleria

This is my html (im using Galleria Image Gallery - JQuery Based)

```
<div id="galleria">
            <img alt="Productname 1" src="bens_img/1.jpg">
            <img alt="Productname 2" src="bens_img/2.jpg">
            <img alt="Productname 3" src="bens_img/3.jpg">
            <img alt="Guess what?" src="bens_img/4.jpg">
        </div>
```

Pseudo Code

```
Get string from <alt> from <img>
Create a new <li> and paste the <alt> string from <img> in it
```

This should be done with all (ie: four) img alt strings. It should look like this:

```
<ul class="textformat">
<li>Productname 1</li>
<li>Productname 2</li>
<li>Productname 3</li>
<li>Guess what?</li>
</ul> <!-- yeah this was all done by java-script -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

```
$("#galleria > img").each(function(i, ele) {
  $(".textformat").append("<li>"+$(ele).attr("alt")+"</li>");
});
```

Comment: `@lonesomeday` very true, used `.attr()` here for the purpose of showing off the maximum amount of jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img[alt]")
```

for tag every image that has 'alt'

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.attr` jQuery selector:

```
$('#galleria > img').each(function(){
  $('.textformat').append('<li>'+ $(this).attr('alt') +'</li>');
});
```

Or you can use `$('#galleria').find('img')` or `$('#galleria').children('img')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `map()` function:

```
$('#galleria img').map(function() {
  return '<li>' + this.alt + '</li>';
}).appendTo('ul.textformat');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend galleria to put the alt tags or descriptions in another div, not sure how to put it into an li, some jQuery i guess 

`extend: function() {
this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {
$('.caption').html(this.$('info-description').html());
})
}`